# Scheduling jobs every N minutes at different days

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduling, scheduler

I have to run a cronjob in particular times:

First one: weekdays between 9:00 - 18:00 every 2 minutes

Second one: saturdays between 10:00 - 18:00 every 2 minutes

The farthest I could get is this:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    (new SendSMS())->run();
})->weekdays()->between('9:00', '18:00');
```

I don't know how to add the everyTwoMinutes constraint since I only found these methods:

```
->everyMinute();    
->everyFiveMinutes();
->everyTenMinutes();
->everyThirtyMinutes();
```

And the second problem is that for the second condition I don't want to add another schedule like these:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    (new SendSMS())->run();
})->saturdays()->between('11:00', '18:00');
```

I would to write a single one matching both times, is it possible?

Comment: You can't create one cronjob  that run with different  hours depend on day, but in laravel you have to implement some logic in your schedule to acheve the desired intervals (Hint: use `when()`)

Comment: If I use the method `when`, when is executed the job? I mean, the task is executed when the closure returns true but when is this closure executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** : This will run at the desired intervals.

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        echo $datetime;
    })->everyMinute()->when(function() {

        $now = new \DateTime();

        # don't run on Sundays
        if ($now->format('l') == 'Sunday') {
            return false;
        }

        # run every two minutes
        if ($now->format('i')%2 == 1) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($now->format('l') == 'Saturday') {
            $start_date = new \DateTime('today 10:00');
            $end_date = new \DateTime('today 18:00');
            return ($start_date <= $now && $now < $end_date);
        } else {
            $start_date = new \DateTime('today 09:00');
            $end_date = new \DateTime('today 18:00');
            return ($start_date <= $now && $now < $end_date);
        }
    });
```

Comment: the `->weekdays()` wont avoid to reach the `if ($now->format('l') == 'Saturday') {` part?

Comment: Fix: use `everyMinute()` instead of `weekdays()`, and don't run on Sundays

Comment: Ok, I'll take it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own custom function in a class that extends `Event`

```
public function everyTwoMinutes()
{
    return $this->cron('*/2 * * * * *');
}
```

Comment: Looks good but how can I use it? How can I make this use my custom Event? $schedule->call(...)->everyTwoMinutes();

Comment: I usually make a App\Lib folder where I keep my custom classes. Call it CustomEvent or something like that. Make sure it extends Event. Then at the top of your controller, import your class like so: `use App\Lib\CustomEvent;`. Then, you'll be able to use that function.

Comment: I know how to use a class in a Controller, I want to make the scheduler use it instead of the Event when I make $schedule->call(); see that there isnt any instantiation

Comment: Use `\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::macro('everyTwoMinutes', function () { 
return $this->spliceIntoPosition(1, '*/2'); });` so that you can call it like `$schedule->call(...)->everyTwoMinutes();`